# Will Coverity treat global variables as 0-initialized in embedded C?

Tags: c, static-analysis, coverity

In embedded C code, we don't explicitly initialize global variables to 0, as the boot code will do that when system boots.
There are two global variables in my code, for example, A and B. My code will promise that A will no longer be larger than B as long as they have a zero initial value.
But when I check a Coverity reported issue, it supposed A might be larger than B. It seems that Coverity didn't think they both have an initial value 0.

Comment: Please show us the code. Read this: [mre]

Comment: Does the issue disappear if you explicitly initialize them to 0?

Comment: I would never *assume* - if you are *relying* on a variable being initialised to zero, it is prudent to *actually* initialise it so.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't assume anything. In Embedded System's firmware, all uninitialized global variables will go into .bss, and it will be cleared to zero explicitly.

Comment: @hyde Yes, when I explicitly initialize them to 0, Coverity won't complain any more. It seems that Coverity won't recognize that uninitialized global variables are cleared at system boot.

Comment: `.bss` is a rather `gcc` specific term...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Synopsys's reply, Coverity doesn't track global variables. It infers from context that a defect is possible when the values of the variables are unknown.
[Here](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Coverity-Analysis-can-not-find-defects-in-a-function-that-uses-global-variables)'s a reference article.